# android: assigning a number to a specific image

Tags: android

I am creating a a card game using a standard deck of 52 playing cards. I want to generate a random number between 0 and 52 and depending on the number,  draw the assigned card to that number.  How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's suppose you have an Activity like this:

```
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainLayout);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myCard);

    Randon ran = new Random();
    int number = ran.nextInt(51);

    switch(number){
        case (0):
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.card0);
        case (1):
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.card1);
        case (2):
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.card2);
        //Rest of cases
    }
}
```

Now let's suppose you have a **mainLayout.xml** file inside the **res/layout** folder that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myCard"
    android:src="@drawable/initialViewOfTheCard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

There you have! It's very simple but I think you'll got the idea!

Edit: I suggest you to investigate how to use GridLayouts in your layouts! That will make the things a lot easier in order to show a lot of cards at the same time!

Edit2: You can model a Card POJO with the drawable id and the card number as attributes! Then you can have a List of Card objects and you could use a ListAdapter in order to populate the GridView!